# Installing Concrete version 5.6.3.4

Tags: php, mysql, installation, wamp, concrete5

So I downloaded an earlier version of concrete because I like the navigation for the admin better than the new one. The new version was easy to install but the older version is starting to become a pain. Would anybody know how to install the earlier version? Thanks in advance.

I downloaded the source files from here
https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5-legacy/zipball/master

When I downloaded the older version I got this 
[image]

I went into the "web" folder and found the regular concrete files there and when I wrote the path to the index file, nothing happens.

[image]

Here is the path in the browser I used
http://localhost/carSite/web/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easyer to download and install it from https://www.concrete5.org/download (see legacy section).
With the github version you need to collect dependencies with composer. That's probbably why it's not working.

Here's a link to the install docs in the 'legacy' documentation for the 5.6 branch: http://legacy-documentation.concrete5.org/developers/installation/installing_concrete5.

I do however advise you to rethink on starting a new site using the 5.6 branch. 
5.7 has many advantages, and allthough there are some tools to help you with migrating from the 5.6 to the 5.7 branch, there is no straight upgrade path.

Also, the new version 8 is on it's way. (You will be able to upgrade from 5.7 to v8)